How do I create a Custom BottomNavigationBar like the image provided in Flutter Using CustomPainter?
I am a novice while working with Flutter CustomPainter. I am trying to implement a BottomNavigationBar like the image provided below.

The BottomNavigationBar is static. There is no animation or change in the curve while clicking on the buttons. And there is no transition of pages.
I tried with some packages, but they either have an animation to the BottomNavigationBar or do not have the curve. And the buttons are asset images.
Please, help me here to implement the design.

Refer this answer

The reference is a very good solution. However, when I try to add the text, it causes issues like positioning and height-width overflow. @RavindraS.Patil

Just managed it using SizedBox

I've updated my answer @MehediHasan to address the requirements

Does How to make bottomNavigationBar notch answer your question? if not please consider including minimal error reproducible code-example

I hope you consider this one,
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [FloatingActionButton].

void main() {
  runApp(const FloatingActionButtonExampleApp());
}

class FloatingActionButtonExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FloatingActionButtonExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: const FloatingActionButtonExample(),
    );
  }
}

class FloatingActionButtonExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const FloatingActionButtonExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<FloatingActionButtonExample> createState() =>
      _FloatingActionButtonExampleState();
}

class _FloatingActionButtonExampleState
    extends State<FloatingActionButtonExample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('FloatingActionButton Sample'),
      ),
      body: const Center(child: Text('Press the button below!')),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            debugPrint('Hi I am DevQt');
          });
        },
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        ),
        child: const Icon(
          CupertinoIcons.stop,
          grade: 5.0,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        notchMargin: 6.0,
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        color: Colors.amberAccent,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                    iconSize: 25,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.speaker),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'End Session',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                    iconSize: 25,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.video_camera),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The code wasn't originally mine; I just used a source code from FloatingActionButton class for the instant implementation of the widget and Flutter 3.10: Floating Action Buttons for achieving the FloatingActionButton with notched BottomNavigationBar. Then I just play around with the code XD.
And this is the design output:

Update
To follow these requirements:

The answer must reflect the UI design from the image provided. The
bottom navigation bar is 67px high, and with the top button, it is
102px in total. It should not break or overflow.

I refactored the code into:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [FloatingActionButton].

void main() {
  runApp(const FloatingActionButtonExampleApp());
}

class FloatingActionButtonExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FloatingActionButtonExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: const FloatingActionButtonExample(),
    );
  }
}

class FloatingActionButtonExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const FloatingActionButtonExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<FloatingActionButtonExample> createState() =>
      _FloatingActionButtonExampleState();
}

class _FloatingActionButtonExampleState
    extends State<FloatingActionButtonExample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('FloatingActionButton Sample'),
      ),
      body: const Center(child: Text('Press the button below!')),
      floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
        height: 35, // as per requirements and to achieve a rounded appearance
        width: 35, // as per requirements and to achieve a rounded appearance
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              debugPrint('Hi I am DevQt');
            });
          },
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 2.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
          ),
          child: const Icon(
            CupertinoIcons.stop,
            grade: 5.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        height: 67.0, // as per requirements
        notchMargin: 6.0,
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        color: Colors.amberAccent,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                child: IconButton(
                  iconSize: 25,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.speaker),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                child: Text(
                  'End Session',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                child: IconButton(
                  iconSize: 25,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.video_camera),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I did a simple arithmetic on this but for the corresponding widget only, a bottom navigation bar 67px high and the top button 35px high (without mentioning the width to maintain the UI aesthetic to appear as a circular button) to get a total of 102px. Don't mind the
notchMargin: 6.0

because it doesn't affect your fixed total height of 102px (i.e., a combination of the bottom navigation bar and top button)
I tested out with the Google Chrome browser using the developer tools in a device mode:
For Mobile S - 320px resolution

For Mobile M - 375px resolution

For Mobile S - 425px resolution

And if you still want to make things responsive (i.e., It should not break or overflow) from which you want to...

Then, you may apply these code changes if so:
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        height: 67.0,
        notchMargin: 6.0,
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        color: Colors.amberAccent,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                    iconSize: 25,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.speaker),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'End Session',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                    iconSize: 25,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.video_camera),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),


I have tried BottomAppBar. I did not find properties to curve the corners of the BottomAppBa, and the shadow property does not match the design.

Kindly apply the portion of the code from the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79183398/how-do-i-create-a-custom-widget-like-the-image-provided-in-flutter-using-customp/79200180?noredirect=1#comment139659305_79200180:~:text=you%20want%20to...-,Then%2C%20you%20may%20apply%20these%20code%20changes%20if%20so%3A,-bottomNavigationBar%3A%20BottomAppBar(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20height

If you properly follow the source code I've provided, you'll get what you need (i.e., desired output). But you need to accept the fact that you have to do your part if you have other concerns that are unrelated to the given problem here.

I need to be specific here; I mean the source code I've modified XD

I don't think I would get the output like the image without CustomPainter. I tried wrapping it with a Container and providing shadows and circular borders. However, It takes the shadow to the middle button like a straight line.

@MehediHasan, I don't think you question is well structured, it seems you wanted a bottom nav bar with a notch, which the code above provides. But your comment suggests you actually want someone to build the Stop button (thats in the middle) in the image with Custom Painter, which is it?
